# Learning while you are sleeping

Tags: sleep, lucid-dreaming, dreaming

Just to clarify, I'm not asking about [Hypnopaedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep-learning), but about using a [lucid dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucid_dream) as a training/rehearsal stage.

[The Lucidity Institue](http://www.lucidity.com/LucidDreamingFAQ2.html#rehearsal) claims:

> ... **many people
>   use lucid dreaming to rehearse for
>   success in waking life. Examples of
>   such applications include public
>   speaking, difficult confrontations,
>   artistic performance and athletic
>   prowess**. Because the activity of the
>   brain during a dreamed activity is the
>   same as during the real event,
>   neuronal patterns of activation
>   required for a skill (like a ski jump
>   or pirouette) can be established in
>   the dream state in preparation for
>   performance in the waking world.

German Scientist [Daniel Erlacher](http://www.dw-world.de/dw/article/0,,2040400,00.html) seems to concur, at least in regard of physical training:

> Martin Spies-Sweetland used his lucid
>   dreams to practice long jump.
>   **Everything he learns in his waking
>   dreams can then be applied to real
>   life**.

---

**Is it really possible that things you learn in a lucid dream can be applied to real life?**

Comment: I’m not sure how evidence for / against this will look like. I know several people (me included) who *have* learned something in dreams. Of course that’s not “evidence” because it’s just anecdotes but it’s pretty conclusive: you *can* learn something in dreams, it happens all the time. How would I go about disproving this?

Comment: I have little doubt that you can learn "some" things. But how about "throwing a basketball"? If you are a bad player, could you use lucid dreams as a training ground? Can your brain create such a realistic simulation (e.g. gravity, aerodynamics, muscle tonus,...) that what you learn in a dream is actually applicable in real life?

Comment: @Oliver_C That’s a really specific question (and I’m inclined to say “no”). Interesting, though.

Comment: I don't think I can use my flying skills while I am lucid dreaming in real life...

Comment: You wouldn't need to clarify many things if the **title** were "**Learning skills while you are lucid dreaming**"

Comment: great question. After having accepted the reality of lucid dreaming the more outlandish "learn to skate while dreaming" claims have intrigued me a lot

Answer (score 6):

Related research (in no particular order) - The articles cited below are focused on Mental Imagery, not Lucid Dreaming; but they might help someone find more relevant research.

It is clear that **appropriate mental imagery, *in conjunction with physical practice*, can be as beneficial as physical practice alone for improving cognitive components of physical performance**; this includes things like "throwing a basketball" (in fact, most of the mental rehearsal research that I've read about used free throws as the physical activity).

Jones, L. & Stuth, G. (1997) [The uses of mental imagery in athletics:](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B7CRT-4FKXK9M-6&_user=10100718&_coverDate=05/31/1997&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=gateway&_origin=gateway&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_acct=C000054465&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10100718&md5=e9342676d44ac059bc5af967ccadcade&searchtype=a) An overview. *Applied and Preventative Psychology*, 6(2), pgs 101-115

Driskell, J.E., Copper, C, & Moran, A. (1994) [Does Mental Practice Enhance Performance](http://web.rollins.edu/~jdriskell/mentalpractice.pdf). *Journal of Applied Psychology*, 79(4), pgs 481-492

Bernier, M. & Fournier, J.F. (2010) [Functions of mental imagery in expert golfers](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6W6K-507CRTX-1&_user=10100718&_origUdi=B7CRT-4FKXK9M-6&_fmt=high&_coverDate=11/30/2010&_rdoc=1&_orig=article&_origin=article&_zone=related_art&_acct=C000054465&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10100718&md5=184ec6af441d7b47e9bc08d0f8835706).  *Psychology of Sport and Exercise*, 11(6), pgs 444-452

Peynircioglu, Z.F., Thompson, J.L., & Tanielian, T.B. (2000) [Improvement Strategies in Free-Throw Shooting and Grip-Strength Tasks](http://www.connectseward.org/shs/da1/research/free%20throw.pdf). *The Journal of General Psychology* 127(2), pgs 145-156

Comment: thanks for the interesting links, I have edited them all into your answer.

Comment: @Oliver_C - thank you for making that more readable and integrated!

Answer (score 1):

There have been some interesting studies by Robert Stickgold at Harvard Medical School that show sleep's role in learning. In an article from *Scientific America* titled [Tetris Dreams](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=tetris-dreams), author  Kristin Leutwyler provides an overview of some of Stickgold's experiments.

> The idea that sleep, and in particular dreaming, serves to cement new information and skills in the brain first gained a lot of attention when Stickgold and his colleagues described another set of findings in the March 1999 issue of the *Journal of Cognitive Neuroscience.* ... They showed that subjects who had slept for six hours or more after learning a new task -- in this case, spotting a visual target on a screen as quickly as possible -- improved, whereas those who didn't sleep on it didn't. Moreover, they found that those who improved the most slept for eight hours, with ample time for both slow-wave and rapid eye movement (REM) periods of sleep.

For more information, check out [this Radiolab podcast](http://www.radiolab.org/2007/may/24/dreams/), which includes an interview with Stickgold and talks about his work in this field.

Comment: I don't think that the normal process of unconscious learning during sleep has much to do with the question of whether you can learn stuff during lucid dreaming.